# Django rest framework wont display data when doing a filter

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I haven't used Django RF in a while and I ran into a problem. I was trying to do an object.get() and I got an error that said It returned more than 1 (returned 2) so I changed the .get to .filter and It fixed my error issue but it won't show any data when going to the endpoint, even though when printing in the console it shows that I've received a queryset (but its an array, [, ]). Heres my ViewSet:

```
class TeamViewSet(ModelViewSet):
queryset = Team.objects.all()
serializer_class = TeamSerializer
permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]



@action(detail=False, methods=['GET','PUT'], permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated])
def me(self, request):
    # return Response(request.user.id)
    try:
        team = Team.objects.filter(leader__user_id=request.user.id)
        print(team)
    except Team.DoesNotExist:
        team = None
    if request.method == 'GET':
        
        serializer = TeamSerializer(team)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = TeamSerializer(team, data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

It's problem an easy fix, I've just haven't used Django RF in a while, Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Try team = Team.objects.filter(leader__user_id=request.user.id).first()

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I just had to include 'many=True' when making the serializer. New Code for reference:

```
class TeamViewSet(ModelViewSet):
queryset = Team.objects.all()
serializer_class = TeamSerializer
permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]



@action(detail=False, methods=['GET','PUT'], permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated])
def me(self, request):
    # return Response(request.user.id)
    try:
        team = Team.objects.filter(leader__user_id=request.user.id)
        print(team)
    except Team.DoesNotExist:
        team = None
    if request.method == 'GET':
        
        serializer = TeamSerializer(team, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = TeamSerializer(team, data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
```